# libnfc: SCL3711 "No NFC device found" on Windows 7

Tags: c++, c, windows, nfc, libusb

I am attempting to use libnfc to allow NFC operations on Windows 7. I am using the SCL3711. The device shows up when running testlibusb, so it would seem that LibUSB is functioning correctly. However, when I run the libnfc test application nfc-list I get the message "No NFC device found". Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not. It would seem that the library is not yet stable on Windows. I had to move to a Linux environment.

Comment: I am now using [nfcpy](https://launchpad.net/nfcpy) on Windows and it works perfectly.  If you want a quick example of it working use Android beam to send an NDEF message to the snep-test-server.py example.